# C++ Derived class virtual function not being overridden

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a base class called `Base` and 2 derived classes called `Derived` and `Combined`. `Combined` takes in 2 instances of `Derived` class. When I run `Combined.Run(input)`, the virtual function `Update` is being overridden, which is what I want. However, when I run `B1.Update(B1.x)` and `B2.Update(B2.x)` (within `Combined.Update()`), the virtual function `Update` are not being overridden. I want `Derived.Update()` to be called when I run `B1.Update(B1.x)`. How can I fix this? Below is the code and console output. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    vector<int> x;

    Base(vector<int> x0) : x(x0) {}

    virtual int Update(vector<int> x) {
        cout << "Base Update" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int Run(int input) {
        return Update(x) + input;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(vector<int> x0) : Base(x0) {}

    int Update(vector<int> x) {
        cout << "Derived Update" << endl;
        return x[0];
    }
};


class Combined : public Base {
public:
    Base B1;
    Base B2;
    Combined(Base& b1, Base& b2)
        : Base({ 0, 0 }), B1(b1), B2(b2) {}

    int Update(vector<int> x) {
        cout << "Combined Update" << endl;
        return B1.Update(B1.x) + B2.Update(B2.x);
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived D1({0});
    Derived D2({0});
    Combined C(D1, D2);
    int input = 5;

    cout << "Output = " << C.Run(input) << endl;
}
```

Console output:

```
Combined Update
Base Update
Base Update
Output = 5
```

What I want:

```
Combined Update
Derived Update
Derived Update
Output = 5
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `b1` and `b2` are declared as type `Base`.  That means you are always dealing with a `Base`.  You need a `Base&` or `Base*` to get polymorphism.

Comment: You should also make the method ```Run()``` virtual in the base class, and ```override``` that method in the ```Derived``` and ```Combined``` class if necessary

Comment: I'm not sold on *should* in *You should also make the method Run() virtual*. If the use case is "`Run` does s bunch of common stuff and then call overridden functions for derived-specific behaviour." then Asker's implementation will keep duplication down. If eveyone has a radically different `Run` behaviour with little commonality, then `virtual` `Run` makes more sense.